# Convert an Integer to a String and Trim in 1 Step

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it's possible to convert an integer to a string and trim it within one step.

I have the following object:

currentForm

```
{
id:1,
name:"Abusicus",
value:12203,
period:"Morning",
favoriteSnack:"      "
....
}
```

I need to find a way to check if the values are empty ("") or have something in it.

Eg. favoriteSnack would be considered empty since it's just white space. Currently I use this to check for white space:

```
var validInput = currentForm.every( v => currentForm[v] && currentForm[v].trim().length);
```

But this does not work on fields with values that are integers. I want to do something like this: (Convert the integers to strings and then do a check on all the values)

```
var validInput = currentForm.every( v => currentForm[v] && currentForm[v].toString().trim().length);
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: what's wrong with `currentForm[v].toString().trim().length`?

Comment: This would fail for input of `0`

Comment: `currentForm[v]` would return falsy, and so `currentForm[v].toString().trim().length` would never even be evaluated

Comment: I was responding to the question, not to your comment.

Comment: `currentForm.every` ... would fail anyway ... an object doesn't have an `every` method, does it?

Comment: I'd go with either `var validInput = Object.values(currentForm).every(v => v.toString().trim().length);` ... or `var validInput = Object.values(currentForm).map(String).every(v => v.trim().length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your object is that, an object, not an array, to use every, first I would map all the keys and cast to a string with + '', then check the condition, like this:

```
var validInput = Object.keys(currentForm)
  .map( v => currentForm[v] + '')
  .every( v => v.trim().length);
```

[jsfiddle in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/vuw9k4ed/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For int, value will be 0, and even you convert, it will be "0", not " "
Regardless, there is a dirty way to do this by adding "" in front of an int.
You can do sonething like this:
"" + value;